# Extreme Server Cooling Part Deux

Tags: home-server, cooling

In a [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/19133/extreme-server-cooling) I asked SU how to seriously cool a (serious) home server. Specs: x2 Opteron Barcelona 2346HE CPUs w/Dynatron A86G HSFs, x8 DIMMs @4GB ECC DDR2 667 regjstered for 32GB total, x4 SATA II hard drives w/3Ware PCIe RAID controller all on a Tyan S2927-E ATX motherboard in an Antec P182 ATX case.

Most people suggested water cooling and I've been sold on it and decided to go that route. After researching the basics and some vendors on water cooling I'm still not fully confident on to how to water cool a *dual* socket F system. Water cooling is an expensive endeavor and I don't want to make any mistakes on the first try. I'm willing to spend the money, but I can't get it wrong on the first shot.

So my question to SU is for water cooling recommendations specifically 2 socket systems. From vendors to products to techniques in cooling, I'm all ears (or rather eyes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to get two compatible processor modules and add it to chain of cooling tubes to the radiator. I think it might really depend on which water cooling system you go with though, they can vary quite a bit. Some have external vs internal radiators, clear tubing with UV coolant, and various other little features.

Comment: Well there in lies the problem with two CPUs. If each block has two nozzles - one for water coming in and the other going out, how can I possibly chain two CPUs together? If the water coming out is the 'hot' water, wouldn't moving that hot water into another processor be unable to move *more* heat? No one really seems to address 2 CPU water cooling.

Comment: Can you do two separate loops to the pump and radiator. One for each processor?

Comment: I have no idea. Do I have to have 2 pumps? Can I split the tubing from the pump and then rebind the tubing from the CPUs to the radiator?

Comment: is there only one in and out in the pump and radiator?

Comment: From what I've seen pumps and radiators only offer 1 in/1 out. Is this where T-intersections come into play for tubing?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. Put T's on both the in and out and run each in/out set to each processor. Might want to check with a water cooling kit manufactor to make sure that is a recommended setup.

Comment: status report? What you find?

Answer (score 1):

Water cooling is not something I would put into a server. Some passive cooling rods with a large 12 or 14 cm. fan is enought with a P182 case from Antec to seriously cool it. Just your main harddrives and CPU have to be properly cooled.

Doesn't the case also have a fan above? This would mean it is ideal for some passive aircooling units with just two case fans.

Comment: The case is *loaded* with fans. it's loud and still not moving enough heat quickly. That's why water cooling seems to be the silver bullet to this problem.

Comment: Use some silent fans and remove any or all obstacles en front of the fan. Sometimes it takes a dremel. I have a similar Antec case with just two running fans and I can barely hear it. Have been sleeping next to it....

Answer (score 1):

High end water cooling is a pretty specialised subject with varying opinions on even minor things like what order you should have the pump, resevoir, water blocks and radiator.  I think your best bet would be to get on some of the specialist water cooling forums (there are lots) and put your questions to the specialists. With your specific situation I guess you'd have to decide whether to set up one loop for each cpu or one big loop with both using a larger radiator and pump.

Comment: Koolance seems to have a very helpful site but seem very pricey in comparison to a few other vendors. Could you recommend a specific board or manufacturer?

Comment: I don't think it's ever a cheap option, unless you want to go the DIY route :-)

Comment: I don't mind spending the cash, I just don't want to *learn* the hardware on the first attempt. That's all.

Comment: I misspoke on my previous comment. > I just don't want to *learn the hard way* on the first attempt.